# Is it standard C++ to assign a member pointer to the address of another member in the constructor initializer?

Tags: c++, ctor-initializer, member-pointers

Does this conform to the standard?

```
class Foo {
    Bar m_bar;
    Bar * m_woo;
public:
    Foo() : m_bar(42, 123), m_woo(&m_bar) { }
};
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is correct. What is not correct is dereferencing that pointer before that particular subobject has been fully initialized.

Comment: And subobjects are initialized in the order they are declared, not the order they appear in the initialization list.  So even if the constructor were written as `Foo() : m_woo(&m_bar), m_bar(42, 123) { }`, `m_bar` would be constructed before `m_woo` is.

Comment: Right @Dennis, but even if the order was the opposite, with the given example it would still be correct, as you can initialize a pointer or reference to the yet uninitialized member. The problem would be if within the initialization list `m_woo` was dereferenced before `m_bar` was initialized.

Comment: No, I understand.  I was clarifying in case he does need to dereference `m_woo` for some other member.  My intuition says the initialization takes place in the order given by the initializer list, and that intuition is wrong.

Comment: @Dennis: Nota bene: GCC warns if the initialiser list has a different order from the declarations.